# Automatic Remote REGEDIT?

Tags: windows, command-line, automation, remote, regedit

I've got a lot of computers on the domain here that do not have remote desktop enabled. I can open the command prompt and do this command:

```
REG.exe ADD \\[the machine im doing this to]\HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\
Control\\"Terminal Server" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0
```

and it works perfectly fine, except for one thing - it makes a prompt asking if I'm sure I want to do this, Yes/No. How would I go about having a batch file auto-answer YES to this, so I don't have to type it every time? It wouldn't be a problem if it was just a couple hundred machines, but there's plenty more than that and it would take a while to do this by hand. Not to mention I might have to sweep a few times to make sure every computer is turned on and is affected by this.

Comment: Why not create a policy that enables RDP?

Comment: I don't have much experience or luck setting group policies. I wouldn't know what to do without breaking everything.

Answer (score 1):

From the output of `reg add /?`:

`/f       Force overwriting the existing registry entry without prompt.`

Just add that to the end of your command.

Comment: Ah! Thank you - I don't know how I missed that option. Guess I should read things a little more carefully.